# set .vim home directory to something specific

Tags: vim, macvim

My projects are all under `/Users/username/workspace/my_project` where `/Users/username/` is `$HOME`.

I want macvim to always have the home as `/Users/username/workspace/my_project` instead of `/Users/username/`.

I understand `set autochdir` sets the home to whatever the current file's directory is, but this is not what I want. 
Also I'm using NerdTree if that helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you want Vim's working directory to be `~/my_project`?

Add `cd ~/my_project` to your `~/.vimrc`.

Do you want all your plugins and colorschemes to be loaded from `~/my_project`, however silly it is?

See `:help runtimepath`.

Comment: I guess I wanted cd `~/my_project` i'm kind of new to Vim :)

Answer (score 0):

add `autocmd VimEnter * :cd ~/my_project/` to your vimrc
the directory will change only when your open vim, and you can decide change to another directory whenever you want use `:cd /directory/`