# How to set a default (permanent) working directory in Vim

Tags: vim, macvim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [set .vim home directory to something specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909841/set-vim-home-directory-to-something-specific)

There is already a question about setting a working directory: [How to set working/current directory in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288756/how-to-set-working-current-directory-in-vim) However my problem is a little different, I have several thousands files (several different projects) in a folder. Whenever I start Vim (MacVim), the cwd is by default set to **home** dir. Thus when I'm using plugins like **ack.vim** they by default are searching in my home dir which is useless. I just want to set it to my **/home/user/Code** folder (which has all my snippets, projects,etc..)

Is there any settings which sets the cwd to a certain directory? Or any workarounds (like executing `:cd /home/user/Code` for every startup in Vim?

Comment: Adding `cd /user/home/Code/` to .vimrc solves it. Voted for closing.

Answer (score 9):

You could just hard-code the current working directory via

```
:cd /home/user/Code
```

in your `~/.vimrc`. But that leads to a strange setup whenever you edit files elsewhere. (And even if you're mainly editing inside your `Code` directory, there is the occasional edit of `~/.bashrc`, or a config setting in `/etc/...`, and so on.

What I do is put the `:cd` into a *local vimrc* inside the `Code` directory. (I use the [localrc.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393); there are others.) Then, the directory is changed only when I actually edit any file withing that directory tree.

Answer (score 5):

You can

```
:se autochdir
```

This will automatically change to the directory containing the opened file.

Or

```
:cd %:h
```

to change to the directory containing the currently opened file now

Comment: This did not work. Every time I close gVim and reopen it and create a new file, again it goes back to home folder. Everytime I have to cd to a different folder to save files there.